# Printing Mapbox on Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, powerbi-embedded

I can't print my report on power bi which includes Map Box visuals because map box isn't certified by power bi. Can we get it certified please?
[Limitations on printing reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFC5p.png)
As you can see that uncertified Power Bi visuals can't be printed.

Comment: Not sure what help we can be, mapbox will have to submit it to MS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/power-bi-custom-visuals-certified

Answer (score 1):

The Mapbox visual is unlikely to be certified, as it sends data outside the Power BI Service. From the [certification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/power-bi-custom-visuals-certified#source-code-requirements) documents it states the following limits:

> Accessing external services or resources. For example, no HTTP/S or
> WebSocket requests can go out of Power BI to any services

As the Mapbox custom visual will need to get map content and other resources from outside Power BI, it will not be certified. There is some talk from the Power BI Team that in the future, visuals like this may go through some limited certification, however there is no timeline stated.